# Slow PHP over ubuntu server | VirtualMachine

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have an Ubuntu-server 12.04LT-64x installed on VMware Player (*I found VMWare works better than Virtualbox after few installations over vb*).

My host computer is an Intel i3 with 6GB-RAM and **windows-8 Pro 64x** installed.
To the guest I gave **3.5GB-RAM and 2Processors** (*connected to web via a bridge*).

Right now php is really slow. I think I configured php pretty well:

1. time limitation 60s
2. 512mb Ram
3. APC installed

But everything is slow. I found out that when using composer (php cli script) things are going really slow, so right now I suspect that this is the cause for it.

*P.S I notice that when I doing `ping google.com` its never stops.. so.. mybe it have any relation..*

Comment: try to `wget` a big file from somewhere and you'll see the download statistics (speed, size, progress). Most likely it's the slow network, rather then the slow php.  
Plus you can run a script that does no networking prefixed with the `time` command and see how long does it take pure php to run.

Comment: An endless ping is normal on Linux machines if you don't set a specific ping count with the `-c` option. So this is unrelated.

Comment: Voting to close. Missing the "professional capacity" - looks like "I have a system at home" (indication for example vmware player vs. virtualbox instead of a real hypervisor like vmware esx or hyper-v or xen). Should be on superuser.

Comment: @Alex Thanks! I remove the virtual connection device and add new one.. and it seems the the CONNECTION PROBLEM(only) solved! BUT, the php/apache/mysql still slow.. and the Drupal hardly loaded..

Comment: @TomTom, Its about UBUNTU SERVER and about LAMP configurations stuff.
it doesn't metter if the deploy machine is sitting at farm or at my home.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines can be slow, there lies your problem; try reconfiguring or get another virtual machine, or consider running it natively instead to avoid any overhead you don't need...